# Sum of Calculated Column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have calculated column Importance_Weight of which I need to create measure that sum questions for related line number.

Importance_Weight = (ColumnX * Average(ColumnY) )/100

Calculated column values for each question is correct as below but when aggrigated by line number the sum is wrong as blow

[image]

I used following measure to calculate sum of questions (q) i.e. L1

LT_WeightPerQuestion:=SUMX(DimQuestion, AVERAGE(Survey[Importance_Weight]))

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use measure as below

LT_WeightPerQuestion = SUM(Survey[Importance_Weight])

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashok thanks for reply, I tried SUM(Survey[Importance_Weight]) but it is giving very high number 603,3.

Comment: I also used following to filter dimension tables to get desire result I am only interested in below lines and question but high number . abc:=
CALCULATE (
  SUM(Survey[Importance_Weight]),
 FILTER ( Survey,Survey[LineKey] IN {3798,3802,3803,3804,3805,3806,3942,3943,3944,3945,3946}
&&  Survey[QuestionKey] IN {507,502,500,492,487,476,463})
)